# XML Validation with CXF, with Specific MinOccurs and MaxOccurs

Tags: jaxb, cxf

I use cxf 2.1 and let cxf validates the soap request by setting

```xml
<jaxws:properties>
    <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
</jaxws:properties>
```

I have xml schema like:

```xml
<xsd:element name="roolInfo">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="a" type="aType"/>
      <xsd:element name="b" type="bType"/>
      <xsd:element name="v" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

When a client sends soap message without 'element v' that is restricted by minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded", I do not understand why cxf on server side throw exception

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'ns2:rootInfo' is not complete. One of '{v}' is expected.
..

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'ns2:rootInfo' is not complete. One of '{v}' is expected.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidComplexType(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3158)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidType(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3105)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processElementContent(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3007)
```

Any suggestions ??

Thank you

Comment: a typo in the xsd:element? roolInfo instead of rootInfo? perhaps rootInfo is defined elsewhere?